# restoring a dump with mongodb fails

Tags: mongodb

I've dumped a mongodb database with the following mongodump command line

```
mongodump -h www.myhost.com -u myusername -p mypassword -d mydb > dump.bson
```

And I'm trying to restore the dump on my local server:

```
mongorestore -h localhost -d mydb dump.bson
```

Unfortunately it fails with the following error:

```
assertion: 10264 invalid object size: 1096040772
```

Does anyone know what could cause this error?
On both servers mongo's version is 1.8.3

Thanks

Comment: Are both 32/64 bit systems? Might also help repairing the original db first before dumping.

Comment: the local server is 64 bits but the remote, I don't know yet actually. Otherwise, I've tried repairDatabase() but sill same error...

Comment: If they're the same bits then it's probably better to ask on the mongodb mailing list. I've had this error once on a small collection and repairing did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because first string output from `mongodump` is "db level locking enabled: 0"

You need to do this

```
tail -n+2 dump.bson > dump_fix.bson
mongorestore -h localhost -d mydb dump_fix.bson
```

Comment: interesting! I'll give it a try, thw for the tip

Comment: In new version of mongo (2.1 stable) this must be fixed. See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/204

Answer (score 6):

excuse my english :P this happened to me when i did export with mongoexport and try to import with mongorestore :D my mistake! i had to use mongoimport.
Remember: mongoexport/mongoimport, and mongodump/mongorestore

i hope this is usefull to some one :P

Comment: That was my mistake this evening as well!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. And finally I found that this problem was caused by using mongodump command in a wrong way.

Comment: Hi @zwalker. It'd probably be a good idea to tell us which command and what you did to fix it :)

Comment: I would agree wutg @TarynEast.

Answer (score 0):

well use mongo restore instead of mongodump

Answer (score 0):

This isn't explained very well anywhere that I found, but I found a solution that worked.

I downloaded a .tgz file from mongolab, which contained .bson and .json files in it. 
I created a ~/dump folder on my mac.
I copied all those .bson and .json files into the ~/dump folder, so I had ~/dump/users.bson for example.

I ran this command in terminal:

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 -db <the_db_name_on_server_this_backup_is_from>
```

It imported in seconds. I'm sure there are other ways/options, but this is what worked for me.