# invalid object size when mongorestoring bson file on 2.4.6

Tags: mongodb, bson

I'm trying to restore a BSON file into a MongoDB collection and I get the following error:

```
me@vm:~$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
me@vm:~$ mongorestore --db test dump/oxyme-data.bson
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Tue Mar  4 18:11:28.839 dump/oxyme-data.bson
Tue Mar  4 18:11:28.839     going into namespace [test.oxyme-data]
Tue Mar  4 18:11:28.839 dump/oxyme-data.metadata.json not found. Skipping.
assertion: 10264 invalid object size: 2064190043
```

There are several reports of this issue, but they are because of an extra debugline that mongodump used to add to the dump, and this is fixed, or at least I'm reasonably sure that's not the problem here because the end and the start of the `.bson` file seem fine.

See for example [restoring a dump with mongodb fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873087/restoring-a-dump-with-mongodb-fails), which has a simple fix that doesn't work for me. There's a bug report https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7007, is this just this bug?

EDIT:

The size of the file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 106M Mar  4 16:01 oxyme-data.bson
```

The version of MongoDB that made the backup is unknown. Isn't BSON a valid standard on it's own as well?

I've checked, and the restore didn't succeed.

Comment: how big is the file? you can run bsondump on it and see where the issue is flagged - here it looks like it already finished the restore.  are you sure the restore failed? this looks like an issue I've seen when there are extra strings at the end of the dump but it's benign and the restore still finished restoring things in that case.

Comment: what version generated your backup?  Did you use -o option to create a single bson file?  the bug you linked is likely a duplicate of SERVER-7259 and it was fixed a while back.